# ''As'' - tense correction

Tags: tense

I have seen a sentence like this:

> She came and stood over him as he lays on the bed

İs it not supposed to be like tist because is is past tense?

> She came and stood over him as he ''laid'' on the bed

Comment: That would mean he was laying eggs!

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of WS2's facetious and unhelpful comment.

Comment: @JavaLatte Over sixty years ago, when I was at school, a fellow pupil reported to our English teacher that someone had left a bag "laying under his desk". "Oh! How many eggs are there?" came the tart reply from the teacher. I have never forgotten it. So whilst I would agree that my comment may have been "facetious", I do not accept that it was "unhelpful". I shall however upvote your good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be 'as he lay on the bed'. 'Lay' is the simple past tense of the verb 'to lie'. That's what you want to match the simple past tense of 'came' and 'stood'. The confusion comes from another verb 'to lay'. 'To lie' means the subject is in a horizontal position. 'To lay' means the subject is putting something else into a horizontal position. You may find this Wiki webpage helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs

Answer (score 2):

There are two different words:

> [lie](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lie) (past lay, pp lain) 
> to position yourself horizontally
>
> [lay](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lay) (past laid, pp laid)
>   to put something else down horizontally
>   to put something down gently
>   to produce eggs (for birds and reptiles)
>   to have sex with somebody (informal)

In this case, he positioned himself horizontally, so the correct verb is the first one (**lie**). The verb **came** is simple past, so we want the simple past  of **lie**, which is **lay**.

If she had put him in a horizontal position, the verb would be the second (**lay**) and the past would be **laid**:

> She **laid** him on the bed

Comment: A comprehensive treatment of lie v lay is given by Professor John Lawler on [English Language Usage - here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie)